# C# dynamic type usage

Tags: c#, dynamic, dynamic-language-runtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should one use dynamic keyword in c# 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674906/when-should-one-use-dynamic-keyword-in-c-4-0)

Hi everyone.

I have a question about the dynamic types in C#. I'm used to work with C# as of non-dynamic language, so I can hardly understand whether to use dynamic types, and the situations when they may be useful.

So can you please expain benefits & takeoffs & perfomance of the dynamic types usage.

Any links & examples would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has multiple questions and answers on SO already, please re-read existing topics before posting your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at answers here: [dynamic keyword vs object data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523031/dynamic-keyword-vs-object-data-type)